# Undefinded index on getting cookie value

Tags: php, cookies, undefined

I'm trying this code:

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = "idmarket";
    $coolie_value = "1";

    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
        echo "Cookie wasn't set";
        setcookie($cookie_name,$coolie_value,time() + 86400);
        echo "Now cookie set : " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    } else {
        echo "Cookie have been set : ".$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }
?>
```

I want to do something if the cookie is not set and do nothing if it's set. but when I try to test if the cookie now is set and echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] I get `Notice: Undefined index: idmarket` instead.

Comment: From the manual (emphasis mine): "*Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next page load** with the $_COOKIE array. Cookie values may also exist in $_REQUEST.*" - this means that you cannot access it directly after setting it - you need to reload first.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul this is what I get :  `array (size=2)
  '_ga' => string 'GA1.1.1600023990.1498488379' (length=27)
  'PHPSESSID' => string 'knsh102nhreq9qk7obgkfjgf22' (length=26)`

Comment: @Qirel Oops good point. I was guessing that.. thank you